# Symfony2 - Force User to complete profile

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, access-control

I'm struggling to find a reusable and not a hardcoded solution for this problem.

At my registration page I'm asking as little information as possible to let the user sign up.
After they have completed that step a User is created.

Before they can use other parts of the application I want them to complete their profile.
(I know it's probably better to make this optional but for this Use Case it's mandatory).

I already have a flag **profileComplete** set to false when they sign up but I feel like doing this flag check in every controller is a bad way to enforce the profile completion.

Is there a more OO way in Symfony using an EventSubscriber or a custom role (USER_PENDING) to solve this problem? How would I set the additional firewall for that role?

Comment: If I had to do this, I'd probably go with the role solution!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutly, I already did it !

**1)** First create your listener :

```
<?php

namespace Sybio\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Services\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;

/**
 * User listener : redirect user depending on his informations
 */
class UserListener
{
    /**
     * @var Container
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * @var Router
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param Container $container
     * @param Router $router
     */
    public function __construct(Container $container, Router $router)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if ($this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()
            && $this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_PENDING')
            && $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller') != 'Sybio\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Controller\UserController::completeInformationAction'
            && $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller') != 'Sybio\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Controller\SecurityController::logoutAction'
            && HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST == $event->getRequestType()
        ) {
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('sybiowebsite_user_complete_information')));
        }
    }
}
```

Note :

1. Check if the user is logged and then having ROLE_PENDING (which means incomplete profile)
2. Test if the user is not already in the action where he can complete its profile, otherwise you'll have an infinite redirect loop !
3. Allow user to logout (optionnal, of course)
4. Check if you are in a master request, otherwise it will be applied also to ESI, render action (render_controller in twig), etc ... and it will crash !

If all conditions are true, the listener redirect to the complete profile page !

**2)** Register your listener :

```
# services.yml or config.yml
sybio.user_listener:
        class: Sybio\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Services\Listener\UserListener
        arguments:
            - @service_container
            - @router
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest}
```

**3)** The last step is to define when a user profile is incomplete and so to give it the ROLE_PENDING:

```
// Entity -> User.php :

    /**
     * Get Roles (security)
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        $roles = array();

        // Manage your roles ...

        if (!$this->email) { // or what you want
            $roles[] = 'ROLE_PENDING';
        }

        return $roles;
    }
```

That's it !

Comment: Please do dependency injection correctly. Why do you have the container? Why aren't you type hinting on interfaces (`RouterInterface`, `SecurityContextInterface`)? Also, I think matching the route is simpler than the full action name, i.e. `$event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route')`.